# django orm filter doesn't find the result but I know the result exists

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a mySql database in server and it has about 5000 rows of data in one table. my model is like this:

```
class Names(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descriptions = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    count_stars = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    count_visited = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    count_shared = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Genders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    root = models.ForeignKey(Roots, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

my mission is to find a specific row in the database by the field of 'title', when the title is in the first tens of rows in the database, everything works good but when the title is in the deeper rows, it can not find it. my view function is:

```
@api_view(["Get"])
def get_name_by_name(request, keyName):
    value = models.Names.objects.filter(title=keyName).first()
    serializedValue = serializers.nameSerializer(value)
    result = serializedValue.data
    return Response(result)
```

database rows:

```
1- found
2- found
.
.
n- not found
.
.
5000. not found
```

what is the problem?

I searched about async programming but it didn't work

Comment: A simple way to debug this would be to perform `models.Names.objects.filter(title=keyName).count` to count the number of queryset results you got and then do a direct COUNT SQL query in the database and compare the two. Ideally the counts should be same.

Comment: Another debug approach would be filter `title__icontains='substring'` to pull out a manageable number of rows and find out why the equality isn't. Null bytes, '0' vs 'O'  and '1' vs 'l' confusion, ... If the data isn't fully under your control then letting users do `icontains` searches is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My data was not English and when I wanted to use browser to call an api with a non English key, the browser didn't recognize it and didn't find the row. So I used another way than browser tab to call my database api and it worked perfect.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35478238)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).